# How to differenttiate between intents coming from two different activies?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

I have three activities in my Android studio project, say activities A,B and C.
There is are two buttons each in activities A and B. And on clicking on both of them, I need to switch to Activity C.

My question is, how do I differentiate  between the two intents coming from A & B to C?

Comment: Put an extra on the `Intent` that indicates the origin of that `Intent`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate.

Comment: [The documenation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#Building) shows how to build an `Intent`, including using extras. There are a series of `putExtra()` methods on `Intent` and a corresponding series of `get...Extra()` methods (where `...` is based on a data type, so we have `getStringExtra()` and `getBooleanExtra()`). A and B can each call `putExtra()` on their `Intent`, and C can retrieve the extra via the appropriate `get...Extra()` variant.

Answer (score 1):

if you know how to pass data from intent why cant you pass extra data that differentiate buttons like

```
intent.putStringExtra("Button", "A");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate intents by passing different data to them

e.g.

```
// Activity 1
Intent one = new Intent(.....,...);
one.putStringExtra("source", "activity_one");
startActivity(one);

//Activity 2
Intent two = new Intent(.....,...);
two.putStringExtra("source", "sctivity_two");
startActivity(two);
```

in target activity

```
// May return null
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("source");

if(s != null && s.equals("activity_one"){
   /// do stuff
}else if(s != null && s.equals("activty_two")){
   /// do stuff
}
```

Comment: getStringExtra (String name)  can return null, so, you need to test for nullability before invoking equal on the returned String..

Answer (score 0):

You may add a flag in the intent extras and retrieve the flag to identify the source activity for example:
In activity A:

```
btnA.setOnClickListener{
    val intent = Intent(baseContext, C::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("ORIGIN", "A")
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

In activity B:

```
btnB.setOnClickListener{
    val intent = Intent(baseContext, C::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("ORIGIN", "B")
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Then inside activity C `onCreate()`:

```
val origin = intent.extras?.getString("ORIGIN", "")
    if (origin.equals("A")){
        //Do something
    }
    else{
        //Do something else
    }
```